# Evaluation of a Laplace transform for e^-at does not give expected results

Tags: syntax

```
LaplaceTransform[E^-at, t, s]
```

That is my input, and the output I am expecting is `1/(a + s)`, but I am getting `(E^(-at))/s`.

Why is this so? How can I remedy this?

Comment: `at` is a single variable of that name; you probably wanted `E^(-a t)`; notice the space indicating multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LaplaceTransform[E^(-a t), t, s]`. Without the space, *Mathematica* thinks `at` is a term, not a product.

Comment: Noob mistake. Wow kind of embarrassing... Thank you so much.